# PHP: str_replace multiple cases

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to create a function for filtering what users post.

```
$postcontent = str_replace(("rn", '<br>'), ("[B]", '<b>'), self::$post);
```

Tried to use it for str replace with multiple strings, but has you can see it is wrong. I also tried:

```
$postcontent = str_replace(
array("rn", '<br>'),
array("[B]", '<b>'),
$self::$post
);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: how do determine that it's wrong?

Comment: Yes the first one is wrong because you didn't defined it as an array and the next one is wrong because you have defined `$self` instead of `self` and even though can't say its perfect because don't know what does that `$post` variable contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used what you are doing with my own custom string.
I created 2 arrays, one with to find and one with replacements, as follows:

```
$search = ["fruit", "veg"];
$replace = ["pizza", "chips"];
```

From here, I then created the string to search:

```
$string = "Eating fruit and veg is good for you!";
```

And then using `str_replace` as such:

```
print str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

I got this result:

> Eating pizza and chips is good for you!

As you can see, using an array within the `str_replace` function works!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument for `str_replace`, string or string array, always refers to the needle.

The second argument for `str_replace`, string or string array, always refers to the replacement.

It should work like this:

```
str_replace(
    ["rn",   "[B]"],
    ["<br>", "<b>"],
    self::$post
);
```

In case you are wondering, `[...]` is identical to `array(...)`, although it is new and less used.